# Java String Equals() method and multidimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, equals

Here is what I'm trying to do:

Write an application that stores at least four different course names and meeting days and times in a two-dimensional array. Allow the user to enter a course name (such as "CS 110") and display the day of the week and time that the course is held (such as Th 3:30). If the course does not exist, display an error message.

Here's the code I have:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Schedule {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //declare variables and arrays
        final int NUM_RANGES = 3;
        int sub = NUM_RANGES - 1;

        String[][] classNames = {
            {"CS 2401", "TS 5697", "UO 7896"},
            {"Tue 8:30", "Thu 7:30", "Fri 9:15" }
        };

        //get input
        String classInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a class name: ");

        //match to output and print
        while(sub >= 0)
            --sub;

        if (classInput.equals(classNames[0])) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class time is: " + classNames[0][0]);
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (classInput.equals("TS 5697")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class time is: " + classNames[1][1]);
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (classInput.equals("UO 7896")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class time is: " + classNames[2][2]);
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid class     name.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to do the equals method on the first IF but can't figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I tagged this question with 'homework' as it's obviously that...

Comment: As a side note, it seems like the `sub` variable is redundant and can be removed. It will be assigned the value -1 (after the `while(sub >= 0)` loop has completed) and then it is never used again.

Comment: What is `sub` good for, does not make sense to me. Your whole approach is fairly static - just retrieve user input, iterate through the array of courses and compare them with user input (e.g. `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase`).

Answer (score 1):

You need `classNames[0][0]` rather than bare `classNames[0]`.

But really, you shouldn't be using a two-dimensional array for this; you should either use a `Map<String, String>` to map from course-names to meeting-times, or better yet, create a small `Course` class that contains both the course-name and the meeting-time (and any other necessary information), and use a `Map<String, Course>` to map from course-names to instances of `Course`.

Answer (score 0):

In a 2d array (arr) you've got to specify the row and column of the index you want to access (arr[row][column]). Every time. So it looks like you need:

```
if (classInput.equals(classNames[0][0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Java object inherits from java.lang.Object which has `toString()` method. Which returns `String` of the object. every class can override it so a new `toString()` will return a desirable string. But as default it returns some runtime code of this Object.

All in all, your `classNames[0]` converts to String. Do I catch your doubts?

But you have an error here:

```
else if (classInput.equals("UO 7896")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Class time is: " + classNames[2][2]);
    System.exit(0); }
```

You don't have `classNames[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `String` with `String[]` this way. It requires you to iterate through all elements.

```
for(String className : classNames[0]) {
   if(className.equals(classInput)) {
      //found ... do something
   }
}
```

You should use `Map<String, String>` for Key-Value then code would be simple. Also if you have `String` constants use them on left side of equals `"Constant string".equals(var)` this guarantees that `NullPointerException` never happens.

Answer (score 0):

Hey equals is case sensitive try using equalsIgnoreCase. Also use trim() to trim the string so it doesn't have white spaces.